# Usage of array filter in nested json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, filter

My aim is to reference to a specific view (A, B or C) inside a nested `json structure`.

```
this.selected_table = this.all_tables.views.find(x => x)['A'];
```

Is this the correct way to use the filter, because all examples I have found have some conditions inside the `array.find()`. In my case, it would work without conditions, but I have the feeling that the `array.find()` is unnecessary in my case? But, I couldn't find another way.

**JSON Object**

```
all_tables = {  
   "views":[  
      {  
         "A":[  
            {  
               "id":"",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "B":[  
            {  
               "id":"",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "C":[  
            {  
               "id":"",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is used to find a particular element in an array based on whether the inner function returns true. In your example, you're returning `x` which is your object in the `views` array and thus it evaluates to `true`. So, your `.find` is simply just returning the one object in your `views` array (or more specifically the first object in your `views` array). Since this is the case, there is no need for `.find()` and instead you can just reference the object in `views` using its index:

```
this.selected_table = this.all_tables.views[0]['A']
```

See example below:

```js
all_tables = {  
   "views":[  
      {  
         "A":[  
            {  
               "id":"a",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"a2",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "B":[  
            {  
               "id":"b",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"b2",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "C":[  
            {  
               "id":"c",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"c2",
               "username":"",
               "status":"",
               "location":"",
               "positionen":[  
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  },
                  {  
                     "field1":"",
                     "field2":"",
                     "field3":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};

console.log(all_tables.views[0]['A']);
console.log(all_tables.views[0]['C']);
```

Comment: Thanks, your explaining helped me alot :)

Comment: This will only work if you know the view you are looking for is the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
.find(x => x)
```

Will return the first item in the array that is truthy, anything that is not, false, 0, '', undefined or null.

Not sure I follow your question fully but are you looking to find the view that contains an A property and then return that property?

```
const getProp = (views, prop) => {
  const view = views.find(v => v[prop]);
  //Will return the first view that has a property called prop
  return view && view[prop]; // If it found one return the property
};
```

Then you can use

```
const prop = getProp(views, 'A');
```